# Extract field name into new object using JQ

Tags: json, jq

Spring provides information about the environment at the env-endpoint. I would like to simplify the output, which looks something like this:

```
{
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "ports",
      "properties": {
        "server.port": {
          "value": 9110
        },
        "management.port": {
          "value": 9350
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "trees",
      "properties": {
        "oak": {
          "value": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "elephants",
      "properties": {}
    },
    ...
}
```

I'd like to only see the key-value-pairs as output, something like this:

```
{
  "server.port": 9110,
  "management.port": 9350,  
  "oak": "true",
  ...
}
```

Using JQ I tried a few things starting at

```
curl https://localhost:9350/actuator/env/ -s | jq '[.propertySources[].properties[]]'
```

and trying `map`, `select` and `with_entries`, but I can't get it to run.
Can you give me a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `properties` objects, though in order go get that output in return you need to take `value` fields out too.

```
.propertySources | map(.properties) | add | map_values(.value)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B2GMxge2QK)</sup>